# Trouble aligning divs horizontally

Tags: css, html, web

I have two divs and I want to align them horizontally. I'm doing this:

CSS:

```
.horidiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="horidiv">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <div id="sendbutton">Send</div>
</div>
<div class="horidiv">
    <iframe width="300" height="225" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="<gMapsAPI"></iframe>
    <p>Some lines of text</p>
</div>
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missing `vertical-align:top;`

```
.horidiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border:1px solid #999;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Zxm4G/)** (border added to visibility)